# Do stacked RBM's have any benefits/advantages over CNN?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, restricted-boltzmann-machine, deep-belief-networks

Do stacked RBM's have any benefits/advantages over CNN?

If the concern is about  face recognition.